# refextract: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType

Tags: python, docker

I'm trying to use the Refextract library to extract citations from the 'references' session in a PDF academic paper.

Here is my code:

```
from refextract import extract_references_from_file

def extract_citations(uploaded_file_location):
    try: 
        citations = extract_references_from_file(uploaded_file_location)
        
        citations = merge_citations(citations)
        
        unique_citations = {}
        
        for citation in citations:
            raw_ref = citation['raw_ref'][0]
            if raw_ref not in unique_citations:
                unique_citations[raw_ref] = citation
            else:
                pass
        
        unique_citations_list = list(unique_citations.values())
        
        return unique_citations_list
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return []
```

Just ignore the merge_citations function, the program run successfully on my localhost (I use Ubuntu 22.04), but when I run it on Docker (I use Docker Compose to run it all), there is the problem from docker logs:

`TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType`

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

I want to access the Google Cloud Bucket, so I have already debugged and checked the file path, but it is correct, so it seems like the primary problem is caused by the `extract_references_from_file` function.

I've already searched, but there is not any satisfactory solution that works for me. So, I am happy for someone to help me fix it.